# How to remove markers from google maps v3 MapWidget in GWT?

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I am adding markers to my MapWidget using following code snippet:

```
private void updateCenter(LatLng center) {
    MarkerOptions options = MarkerOptions.newInstance();
    options.setPosition(center);
    Marker markerBasic = Marker.newInstance(options);
    markerBasic.setMap(mapWidget);
}
```

But I am not sure how to remove a marker without redrawing/re-instantiating the Map.

Please provide GWT specific answers only.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried implementing the likes of clearMarker(), deleteMarker() and setAllMap() as mentioned in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)?

Answer (score 2):

You can either call [markerBasic.close()](http://branflake2267.github.io/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/javadoc/3.9.0-build-17/com/google/gwt/maps/client/overlays/Marker.html#clear()) or `markerBasic.clear()`. 
Internally they will call `markerBasic.setMap(null)`.